# sort pipe is always sorting caseSensitive (ngx-order-pipe)

Tags: angular

I need to sort a list of asset-items case insensitive by name

I have the following `ngfor` for a component

```
<app-asset-item
          ....
          *ngFor="
            let asset of (contents.assets
              | orderBy: assetFolderOrder.sort:assetFolderOrder.reverse:false:true
              | FilterPipe: filterargs)">

           ....
</app-asset-item>
```

Later in the same html I have this sort button

```
<app-sort-action [options]="assetFolderSortOptions">
</app-sort-action>
```

And in the Typescrit file I have the soring options defined this way

```
  assetFolderSortOptions = [
    { name: "A-Z", data: "name" },
    { name: "Upload date", data: "uploadedOn" }
  ];
```

When said `true` on this third parameter for the orderBy pipe, is supposed to mean "caseInsensitive" ordering but the `ng-for` is showing the elements in "ascii" ordering : first numbers -> upper case -> then  lowe case, I have also tried false (which is the default) without any luck

Here is the ngx-order pipe documentation - 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-order-pipe

What am I missing or doing wrong ? and how do I solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I created a property in the `asset` object called `nameCaseinsensitive`.

For each object in the assset array I did this

```
asset.nameCaseinsensitive = asset.name.toLowerCase() ;
```

And changed the `SortOptions` from `name` to  `nameCaseinsensitive`

```
assetFolderSortOptions = [
    { name: "A-Z", data: "nameCaseinsensitive" },
    { name: "Upload date", data: "uploadedOn" }
  ];
```

Works like a charm but I did not want to do this, I wanted to understand what I was doing wrong